# Why npx does not work for some of the packages?

Tags: prettier, npx, prettier-eslint

`npx eslint` This works fine and executes eslint with out the explicit cli install

on the other hand,

`npx prettier-eslint` This one does not work. //command not found

But if I install `prettier-eslint-cli` above command works fine

My question is why `npx prettier-eslint` command does not work without the cli installation

Answer (score 0):

That's because `npm` is a package **manager** while `npx` is a package *runner*. You can read more about the differences [here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) and [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/).

Comment: I know that difference, what I don't understand is the difference in behaviour for eslint and prettier-eslint here

Comment: You need a  **cli package** for both `eslint` and `prettier-eslint` in order to run them using `npx`. These packages are `eslint-cli` and `prettier-eslint-cli` specifically. The difference is that `eslint-cli` comes pre-packaged as a dependency of `eslint`, whereas `prettier-eslint-cli` does not come pre-packaged with `prettier-eslint`, so you have to install it manually before you can use it.

Comment: Are you trying to say "eslint" install "eslint-cli" as a dependency. In that case where is eslint-cli installed. package-lock.json does not contain it.